# Add html tag R package

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am writing an RMarkdown website and I have some dataframes that have data that I would like to use in my page. For example I am creating a list of headings using the  tag so the user can fold up/down those sections. I am embeding some html code in my Rmarkdown that looks like:

```
   <details><summary>Example1</summary>
   <p>This is my text.</p></details>

   <details><summary>Example2</summary>
   <p>This is my text.</p></details>
```

I created several functions that I use in my Rmarkdown to create the content in the right format (shown above). The functions I have so far are the following:

```
# Function to add summary tag (html)
html5_s <- function(mytext) {
  start <- "<summary>"
  end <- "</summary>"
  paste0(start,mytext,end)
}

# Function to add details tag (html)
html5_d <- function(mytext) {
  start <- "<details>"
  end <- "</details>"
  paste0(start,mytext,end)
}

# Function to add paragraph tag (html)
html5_p <- function(mytext) {
  start <- "<p>"
  end <- "</p>"
  paste0(start,mytext,end)
}
```

However I feel this is a really bad hack and before I proceed any further I have decided to look in CRAN to see if there is a package that do something similar to this. I have not found anything which make me thing I am doing all this wrong.

Comment: request for packages are off topic on SO. So far, it is unclear what you want precisely. Could you add an example with a data.frame to show how you'd use the functions you describe?

Comment: Are you thinking of somethig akin to `tags` in [`shiny`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html)?

Comment: I guess my example could have been clearer but the response from @Symbolix is exactly what I was looking for. Just a simple function to add html tags.